# Javascript Fetch Giving Inconsistent Result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using Expo Go to test out my React Native app. I'm fetching a request from a website using the Fetch API. On the first time that I fetch the data, it seems to be returning `{"next": null, "parent": {"children": [[Circular]], "endIndex": null, "next": null, "parent": null, "prev": null, "startIndex": null, "type": "root"}, "prev": null}`  or sometimes `{}`.

However, if I Ctrl+S, which hot reloads the application, it pulls in all the required data from the fetch request.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, useWindowDimensions, View } from 'react-native';


const EventsScreen = () => {
    const [eventsHTML, setEventsHTML] = useState({});
    const {width} = useWindowDimensions();

    const ParseEventsHTML = ()=>{
        console.log(eventsHTML);
    
    }

    
    const RefreshEvents = ()=>{
        console.log("refreshing events");
            fetch('https://www.thesubath.com/whats-on/')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(textResponse => {
                setEventsHTML(textResponse);
                ParseEventsHTML();

            });
        }

    useEffect(()=>{
        RefreshEvents();
        }, []);
  return (
    <View>
        {!eventsHTML? <ActivityIndicator/> : <Text>Hello world</Text>}
    </View>
  
  )
}
export default EventsScreen;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "bathe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "htmlparser2": "^8.0.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-html-parser": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: "On the first time that I fetch the data, it seems to be returning..." - "seems to be" or "is"? What does the Network tab in dev tools show?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is around when your `eventsHTML` piece of state is actually being updated.  If you take a look at the [setState docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#setstate), you'll see the first Caveat reads:

> The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, [you will still get the old value](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value) that was on the screen before your call.

You need to refactor where you are running your `console.log` so that you can make sure you actually get it when that value updates.  I might try adding another `useEffect` to log each time the `eventsHTML` state updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("eventsHTML changed: ", eventsHTML);
  }, [eventsHTML]);
```

Also, I can say that your `<View>` component is never going to show the `<ActivityIndicator>` on the first load as you are setting it equal to an empty object from the start, so `!eventsHTML` will never actually return truthy.  You may want to remove the `{}` from your `useState` method:

```js
const [eventsHTML, setEventsHTML] = useState();
```

This will make sure that your variable remains `null` until you actually populate it with data.

Comment: Doesn't explain where that `{"next": null, "parent": {"children": [[Circular]] //etc.` object comes from.

Comment: That is the object representation of DOM elements.  Most likely this is how the response is coming back from the request would be my guess.

Comment: No, it isn't, the names of the properties are different. DOM element has: "nextSibling", "previousSibling", "previousElementSibling", "parentNode". This here has "next", "prev", "parent".

Comment: Looks like those are actually the properties of the Cheerio NodeWithChildren.  Are you using Cheerio here at all?  https://cheeriojs.bootcss.com/classes/NodeWithChildren.html